# IVT on monotonic function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> To find the intervals where a function $ƒ$ is increasing or decreasing,
>   we first find all of the critical points of $ƒ$. If $a < b$ are two
>   critical points for ƒ, and if the derivative ƒ′ is continuous but
>   never zero on the interval $(a, b)$, then by the Intermediate Value
>   Theorem applied to ƒ′, the derivative must be everywhere positive on
>   $(a, b)$, or everywhere negative there.

This is from my book. I can see why it is intuitively true, but I can't see why the IVT applies here.

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem we know that, whichever is $y \in (\min \lbrace g(a), g(b) \rbrace, \max \lbrace g(a), g(b) \rbrace)$, there exists some $z \in (a,b)$ such that $g(z)=y$. But, if the function is never $0$, then we must have that it is either always $>0$, or always $<0$, otherwise it would go against this result. Indeed, if there were some $z_1$ for which $g(z_1)>0$ and some $z_2$ for which $g(z_2)<0$, then there would exist $z_3$ for which $g(z_3)=0$, a contradiction. This can be clearly applied to your particular case of $g=f'$.

Comment: It's talking about $f'$ and not $f$.

Comment: I was actually referring to any general function; I will indicate it with $g$ to avoid confusion